# Rails - Nested Form Not Saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have problem and I can't figure out how to solve this, I tried trace every character on codes but I think I didn't get mistake on code

I have 3 models : **Product**, **AttributeProduct** and **AttributeProductRelation**, and relations :

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attribute_product_relations
  has_many :attribute_products, through: :attribute_product_relations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attribute_product_relations, allow_destroy: true
end

class AttributeProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attribute_product_relations
  has_many :products, through: :attribute_product_relations
end

class AttributeProductRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :attribute_product
end
```

And on ProductsController I have this :

```
def new
  @product = Product.new(id: generate_product_id)
  2.times { @product.attribute_product_relations.build }
end

def create
  @store = current_user.store
  @product = @store.products.build(new_product_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.save
      format.html { redirect_to red_path, notice: I18n.t('notice.create_product_success') }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private 

def new_product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:id, :name :description, attribute_product_relations_attributes: [:id, :product_id, :attribute_product_id, :value])
end
```

And this is a form :

```
<%= nested_form_for @product, html: { class: "form-horizontal" } do |f| %>
<%#= order stuff here %>
 <%= f.fields_for :attribute_product_relations do |attribute_product_relation_form| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
       <%= attribute_product_relation_form.hidden_field :attribute_product_id, value: 1 %>
       <label class="control-label">size</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
       <%= attribute_product_relation_form.text_field :value, {class: "form-control text select_short" %>
    </div>
  </div>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And this is a log when I submit a form :

```
Started POST "/products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-09 16:11:51 +0700
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WzSKpXm4AFhETrPyv0Ez/WohxoAMMiiRRc6CNhgIPC8=", "product"=>{"id"=>"2132051", "name"=>"T-shirt", "attribute_product_relations_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"attribute_product_id"=>"1", "value"=>"Medium"}, "1"=>{"attribute_product_id"=>"1", "value"=>"SMALL"}} , "description"=>"cool t-shirt"}, "button"=>""}
```

You can see `attribute_product_relations_attributes` are exists on parameter, So I'm use `pry-debugger` gems to trace `new_product_params` method and I just get this :

```
[1] pry(#<ProductsController>)> new_product_params
=> {"id"=>"2132051",
 "name"=>"T-shirt"
 "description"=>"cool t-shirt"}
```

I can't see `attribute_product_relations_attributes` on `new_product_params` and didn't save to database.

Answer (score 0):

As you are have has many relationship in `new_product_params` methods, it is required to make permit for array of `attribute_product_relations_attributes`.  So, your should refactor `new_product_params` method to

```
def new_product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:id, :name :description, attribute_product_relations_attributes: [ [:id, :product_id, :attribute_product_id, :value] ])
end
```

I think this will help.